# How could I change an image in a child page when pressing a button in its parent page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a DefaultLayout component with a dark mode toggle button which is its own component. One if its children (DefaultLayout's) is About.vue where I want a specific image to change its src depending on a localStorage value that can be set to either 'dark' or 'light'.

I've managed to read the localStorage value but the image does not change unless I refresh the page.

I'm new to Vue so I'm lost on how I can create a method to do this in DefaultLayout and change a variable in its child. I've tried to use an emit with no luck.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple example

```js
Vue.component('About', {
 name: 'About',
 template: `<div>
   <div v-if="mode==='dark'">Dark</div>
   <div v-else>Light</div>
  </div>
 `,
 data() {
  return {
   mode: 'light',
  };
 },
 mounted() {
  this.setMode('white'); // In realtime use `this.getMode()` instead of 'white'
 },
 methods: {
   setMode(val) {
     this.mode = val;
   },
   getMode() {
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mode'));
   }
 }
});

var app = new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 template: `<div>
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="toggler" @input="setVal" />
   <About ref="about" />
 </div>`,
 data() {
  return {
    toggler: false,
  };
 },
 methods: {
   setVal() {
    const mode = this.toggler === false ? 'dark' : 'light';
    // localStorage.setItem('mode', mode); // In realtime uncomment this line
    this.$refs.about.setMode(mode);
   }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the local storage is for keeping data not propagate events.
The simplest way for you is to make [a prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html) in child component and pass the value by this prop. But if you want to implement it as global variable the suggested way is by [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).